# Check value in sublist and return the correct sublist

Tags: python

I have the following lists :

```
list1 = [[1,1],info11,info21]
list2 = [[2,1],info12,info22]
list3 = [list1,list2]
list4 = [1,1]
```

Then this function checks if list4 is in a sublist of list3

```
if any(list4 in i for i in list3):
    #Do something
else:
    #Do something
```

What I want to do is print [info11,info21]. However, I don't really know how to do that.
I tried list3[i] but it didn't work and tells me i is undefined. What should I do?

Comment: Are the nested lists always in the same (zero-th) position?

Comment: Yes they are always at the same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
list1 = [[1,1],'info11','info21']
list2 = [[2,1],'info12','info22']
list3 = [list1,list2]
list4 = [1,1]

for i in list3:
    if list4 in i:
        print i[1:]
```

output will be:- ['info11', 'info21']

Comment: I don't understand why but when I tried this code in python tutor it gave me the following error : SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 8)

Comment: @loumi it's working fine. check where you are doing mistake in your code.

Comment: Ok I just checked it works when I'm in python 2.7 not in 3.3. My bad

Answer (score 0):

you could also use filter for that task

```
>>> list1 = [[1,1],"info11","info21"]
>>> list2 = [[2,1],"info12","info22"]
>>> list3 = [list1,list2]
>>> list4 = [1,1]
>>> filt_list = filter(lambda sublist:list4 in sublist,list3)
[[[1, 1], 'info11', 'info21']]
```

this filters your nested list from unwanted lists. Now it depends if it is safe to say that you'll have only one matching list. If so just take the first element from the list and use slice notation to get all elements starting from 1-th element

```
>>> print filt_list[0][1:]
['info11', 'info21']
```